# Sencha Touch & Phonegap : XMLHttpRequest cannot load app.json

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using **Sencha CMD v4.0.4.84** and **Sencha Touch 2.3.1**

When I ran the Phonegap on my device, the loading screen was stuck.
Then, I compiled a "production" package using

Sencha app build production

And when I entered the **index.html**, I found the problem

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/eMali_test/eMaliApp_v4/build/production/eMaliApp/app.json1410351277105. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

The phonegap's **config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" />
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the reason why Phonegap is stuck? I'd think that you could find out the real reason if you open the production package through an apache running at localhost.

Comment: That's what I found when I opened the production package.